# Can't get options to appear for Dropdownlistfor using jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

For some reason I'm having trouble getting my DropDownListFor Options to appear after doing a jquery AJAX call in my MVC application.  I've seen various posts in regards to this but have still not been able to resolve my particular problem.

My DropDownListFor looks like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedClassifier, new SelectList(Model.classifiers, "Code", "CodeAndDescription"), new { @id = "Classifier", @class = "form-control" })
```

My JSON caller looks like this:

```
  $.getJSON("/Request/LoadDropDowns", { selectedFacilityGroup: selectedItem }, function (results) {
                var toAppend = '';
                $.each(results.classifiers, function (index, result) {
                    toAppend += '<option value=' + "'" + result.Code + "'" + '>' + result.CodeAndDescription + '</option>';
                });
                $('#Classifier').append(toAppend);
        });
```

I know that my data is being returned and toAppend looks something like this:

```
<option value='A'>(A) WORK ITEM 1</option>
<option value='B'>(B) WORK ITEM 2</option> etc.
```

However, I can't get the options to appear.  Anyone willing to assist?

Thanks.

Comment: What MVC application is this? Rails?

Comment: This is an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: You should add this to the title and as a tag on your question :)

Comment: The problem here appears to be that the DropDownListFor is not setting the id properly.  It appears as "parent" when I "View Source" instead of "Classifier".

Comment: Also, in this case I'm selecting an item in 1 dropdownlistfor and want to populate 3 others upon selecting an item in the first.

Comment: This turned out to be a simple oversight on my part and has been resolved.  Thanks to those who responded.